# Implement html tags in SQLite database

Tags: android, html, sqlite

I have entered some text wrapped with html tags in SQLite database, and I want to display those text in phone. for example: I have entered `10<sup>-7</sup>` in SQLite database, I want to render 10<sup>-7</sup> in phone.

This is the image of SQLite from DB Browser for SQLite:
[image]

This is part of the DBHelper:

```java
public List<Quizplay> getQuestionGuj(int cate_id, int sub_cate_id, int noOfQuestion, int level) {

        List<Quizplay> quizplay = new ArrayList<Quizplay>();
        int total = noOfQuestion;
        String sql = "select *  FROM " + TBL_QUESTION + " where (" + CATE_ID + "=" + cate_id + " and "
                + SUB_CATE_ID + " =" + sub_cate_id + " and "
                + LEVEL + "=" + level + ") ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT " + total;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        //SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/" + packageName + "/databases/" + DATABASE_NAME, null, 0);
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Quizplay question = new Quizplay();
                question.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
                question.setQuestion(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("question")));
                question.addOption(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("option_a")));
                question.addOption(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("option_b")));
                question.addOption(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("option_c")));
                question.addOption(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("option_d")));
                String rightAns = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("right_answer"));
                if (rightAns.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                    question.setTrueAns(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("option_a")));
                } else if (rightAns.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                    question.setTrueAns(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("option_b")));
                } else if (rightAns.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                    question.setTrueAns(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("option_c")));
                } else {
                    question.setTrueAns(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("option_d")));
                }
                if (question.getOptions().size() == 4) {
                    quizplay.add(question);
                }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        Collections.shuffle(quizplay);
        quizplay = quizplay.subList(0, noOfQuestion);
        return quizplay;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay! I got your point, you want to add super and sub scripts in your quiz app.
Rather than using latex, you should add superscript and subscript letters in your sqlite db file,
you can find many generators online
https://lingojam.com/SuperscriptGenerator
this is my personal favorite!
generate and copy paste the letter in your sqlite db.

Comment: This does not answer OPs question

Comment: @mishsx i know, but that is better way!
why to write long HTML code if once can easily get the job done with letters?

Comment: If nothing works this can be the last option, but I want the better way. Anyway, thanks.