# org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_NOTADB] File opened that is not a database file (file is encrypted or is not a database) [NETBEANS]

Tags: java, database, sqlite, swing, netbeans

So i got this form that I'm using but I get that error whenever i submit, it says CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL but then it returns the error and never insert nor retrieves anything from the db. I checked the version of the sqlite and everything, can't figure it out.

public class databaseConnection {

```
public static Connection connection = null;

public static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        System.out.println("CONNECTING");
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:SoftwareDB.db");
        System.out.println("CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Connection Failed!");
    }
    return connection;
}

public static void login(String username, String password, String login) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        System.out.println("INSERTING");
        try (Statement stmt = getConnection().createStatement()) {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO login (username, password) VALUES ('" + username + "', '" + password + "', '" + login + "');";
            stmt.execute(sql);
        }
        getConnection().close();
        System.out.println("INSERT SUCCESSFUL");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static ResultSet getLoginDetails(String query) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ResultSet rs;
    try (PreparedStatement ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(query)) {
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ps.close();
        getConnection().close();
    }
    return rs;
}

public static ResultSet getExistentDetails(String query) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ResultSet rs;
    try (PreparedStatement ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(query)) {
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        getConnection().close();
    }
    return rs;
}
```

}

```
private void loginBtnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      

    if (username.getText().isEmpty() || password.getText().isEmpty()) {
        infoLabel.setVisible(true);
        username.setText("");
        password.setText("");
    } else {
        try {
            
            databaseConnection.getLoginDetails("SELECT * FROM register WHERE email = '?' AND password = '?'");
            String ts = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy - HH.mm.ss").format(System.currentTimeMillis());
            databaseConnection.login(username.getText(), password.getText(), ts);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login succesful!");
            new login().setVisible(true);

            infoLabel.setVisible(true);
            username.setText("");
            password.setText("");
        } catch (HeadlessException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed!");
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpsgB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have forgotten an important thing: properly preparing your `PreparedStatement` and opening/closing connections correctly.

Would you try the following rewritten `getLoginDetails()` method and take inspiration from it for the other methods?

```
public static ResultSet getLoginDetails(String query, String email, String password) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ResultSet rs;
    try (Connection conn = getConnection()) {   
        try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
            ps.setString(1,email);
            ps.SetString(2,password);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();    
           // Do something with the ResultSet here or do not close the statement!   
        }
    }
    return rs; // should be something else! (as it could be already closed)
}
```

Then you certainly **need to do something with the `ResultSet`**! For example: check that the email/password combination exists in order to validate the login request.

Also, some important remarks and tips:

- better check that the connection is valid after initialization using `isValid(timeout)`
- think about a connection pool or at least some ways to reuse your connection(s)
- eventually use existing tools (libraries like Apache) for your `ORM` (Object-Relation Mapping) and `DAO` (Database Access Object) layers. Actually, that's highly **recommended**.
- closing a PreparedStatement will automatically close the associated ResultSet. Your code does not take that into account. Cf. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Keep me posted!

Comment: Thank you, those were not actually the problem, it was my format after all, the sqlitestudio didn't do the right format so i had to switch to another sql compiler but those suggestions were also helpful :)

Comment: Glad to read that and thanks for the vote. We can say that I've anticipated the next error then and spared you the next post :)

Comment: can you help me with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62794579/implement-html-tags-in-sqlite-database